# Node-RED running local on a mac: waiting for missing types to be registered

Tags: node-red

when I start node-red i get the following message waiting for missing types to be registered. Then a few nodes are listed which worked before, but are not available anymore. 
How can I get this fixed? btw when I use the -v option while starting i don't get any extra info.

MacProHB:node-red hans$ node red -v

```
Welcome to Node-RED
===================

11 Dec 15:12:33 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.11.1
11 Dec 15:12:33 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.12.3
11 Dec 15:12:33 - [info] Loading palette nodes
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [warn] [sensorTag] Error: Cannot find module'xpc-connection'
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [warn] [tcp] Error: tcp in already registered
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [warn] [udp] Error: udp out already registered
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info] Settings file  : /Users/hans/.node-red/settings.js
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info] User directory : /Users/hans/.node-red
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info] Flows file : /Users/hans/.node-red/flows_MacProHB.local.json
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info] Starting flows
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info]  - sensorTag
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info]  - pushover
11 Dec 15:12:34 - [info]  - ibmiot in
```

Comment: Update the question with the output with -v so we can see which types are missing. Also did you upgrade or change anything from when it worked to when it didn't?

Comment: Please edit your original question as comments have length limits and do not support formatting

Comment: You have not answered the question about what you changed between when it worked and when it started to fail. Did you upgrade or move flow files between machines?

Comment: How did you upgrade node-red?

Comment: You will probably do better discussing this on the mailing list as it will require more debugging https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 3):

Node-Red most probably hangs on start up, because it cannot find modules that have been defined in your 
`/Users/hans/.node-red/flows_MacProHB.local.json` flow.

Easy fix would be to start with a new flow by starting node-red with:

`node-red scratch.json`

Comment: node-red scratch.json
worked for me. I believe I had permissions issues when I installed a few packages as the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience I had to re-install request

npm install request

to have the nodes registered again

Answer (score 0):

Do the following..

1. Restart node red.
2. Restart browser.
3. check whether all packages used in flows are installed from Manage Palette.
4. Reinstall missed package.

I hope this works fine....